# Moving Wordpress site and Theme stopped Jquery script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I moved a Wordpress site I'm building for a client. So far so good. Everything copied across.

Only the home page isn't responding how it should.

As you can see if you view the page source, all the elements have loaded, but they aren't showing for some reason. And I can't work out why!

Could someone please troubleshoot this for me?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body of the site is set to `display: none` here:

```
.home {
display: none;
float: left;
}
```

In this css file

```
/wp-content/themes/insigniaunderwriting/style.css?ver=2013-07-18
```

On your old site you used this css file:

```
/wp-content/themes/insigniamain/style.css?ver=2013-07-18
```

Which seems to indicate that you should switch from *insigniaunderwriting* to *insigniamain*.